# Go rest service deployed in k8s response timeout

Tags: go, kubernetes, memory, containers, timeout

I deployed a go rest service in k8s, limit it's cpu 200m and memory 80Mi. I find that the service occasionally response times out.
When I use command crictl stats, the resource usages of container is

```
CONTAINER        CPU %           MEM              DISK              INODES  
bcadfe1f33510    1.06            75.47MB          32.77kB           10
```

How can I locate the cause of the problem and reproduce it?

I get some goroutine trace info, find that all goroutines wait of net.(*conn).Read

```
-----------+-------------------------------------------------------
        52   runtime.gopark                                        
             runtime.netpollblock                                  
             internal/poll.runtime_pollWait                        
             internal/poll.(*pollDesc).wait                        
             internal/poll.(*pollDesc).waitRead (inline)           
             internal/poll.(*FD).Read                              
             net.(*netFD).Read                                     
             net.(*conn).Read                                      
             net/http.(*connReader).Read                           
             bufio.(*Reader).fill
             bufio.(*Reader).Peek
             net/http.(*conn).serve
-----------+-------------------------------------------------------
         9   runtime.gopark
             runtime.netpollblock
             internal/poll.runtime_pollWait
             internal/poll.(*pollDesc).wait
             internal/poll.(*pollDesc).waitRead (inline)
             internal/poll.(*FD).Read
             net.(*netFD).Read
             net.(*conn).Read
             net/http.(*connReader).backgroundRead
```

There's one more question.
I want to reduce the memory of this service, so I used go pprof to analyze it's memeory.
But I find that it's inuse space of heap memeory is just total 13876.06kB, far below the above data of stats.

I want to locate the cause of the timeout problem and reduce the memory.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at pprof (https://github.com/google/pprof) it will give you a nice graph of your memory usage and can be helpful to find bottle necks and inefficient code